# Phone acceleration relative to initial reference of frame in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, frame, accelerometer

Can I somehow get acceration vector relative to initial reference of frame at any time? (what I mean: reference of frame in xArbitraryZVertical mode, at the first time I got Core Motion data)
What I tried to do:
Everytime I get CM data I multiply new rotation matrix (which locate in attitude property) by old rotation matrix (matrix I got at previous steps by multiplying over and over rotation matrices) and multiply this by acceleration vector. 
But it doesn't seem to work.
Maybe it's a bit silly question, sorry then, but I really don't know how to do what I want. And maybe there is a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Poll the motion manager's `deviceMotion` repeatedly.
2. Each time you receive `nil`, return without doing anything.
3. The first time you receive a non-nil result, save its attitude to an instance property.
4. Every subsequent time you receive a non-nil result, call `multiply(byInverseOf:)` on its attitude, with the stored attitude as the argument. The result is the attitude *change* from the original.

Comment: But I do not know what you mean by _acceleration_ relative to a frame of _reference_. That sounds like comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I mean I want to receive acceleration vector in initial coordinate system at any time.

Comment: Well, I don't know what that means.